# Getting first and last function parameter in Python

Tags: python, function, arguments

I have to make a function with more than 2 arguments in python and in the end I have to print the first and the last argument of the function (in a list).

I have tried like this, but it doesn't work. What am i doing wrong?

```
import inspect

def func(a, b, c):
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    args, _, _, values = inspect.getargvalues(frame)
    for i in args:
        return [(i, values[i]) for i=0 and i=n]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's also a way to get a variable number of function arguments in python (it's called [var-positional](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-parameter)). They then end into a list:

```
def func(*args): # The trick here is the use of the star
    if len(args) < 3: # In case needed, also protects against IndexError
        raise TypeError("func takes at least 3 arguments") 
    return [args[0], args[-1]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You are overthinking this. You already have references to the first and last arguments:

```
def func(a, b, c):
    print [a, c]
```

Comment: I thought that this is too simple. Thank you!